# Express a rule with ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4, greedy, non-greedy

I must define a rule which expresses the following statement: {x in y | x > 0}.
For the first part of that comprehension "x in y", i have the subrule:

```
FIRSTPART: Name "in" Name
```

, whereas Name can be everything.

My problem is that I do not want a greedy behaviour. So, it should parse until the "|" sign and then stop. Since I am new in ANTLR4, I do not know how to achieve that.

best regards,

Comment: Is `|` a valid `Name`?

Comment: no, it should be a delimiter. The whole {x in y | x >0} should represent a mathematical comprehension statement. You can read it as follows: "x is in y with the property that x is greater than 0". For my grammar, I want to divide that statement. Therefore, the parser should read the the first part "x in y" until it reachs "|" and then the second part "x >0".

Comment: But the "|" is not the real problem. What I need is a construct such that ANTLR reads everything what comes before "|". Therefore, "x in y" is only an example. I want incorporate a non-greedy behaviour. It reads everything until "|" and then it stops

Comment: If `|` isn't a valid `Name`, `myRule: name 'in' name '|' expression` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the lexer/parser rules should represent the allowable syntax of the source input stream.

The evaluation (and consequences) of how the source matches any rule or subrule is a matter of semantics -- whether the input matches a particular subrule and whether that should control how the rule is finally evaluated.

Normally, semantics are implemented as part of the tree-walker analysis.  You can use alternate subrule lables (#inExpr, etc) to create easily distinguishable tree nodes for analysis purposes:

```
comprehension : LBrace expression property? RBrace ;
expression    : ....
              | Name In Name     #inExpr
              | Name BinOp Name  #binExpr
              | ....
              ;
property      : Provided expression ;

BinOp    : GT | LT | GTE | .... ;
Provided : '|'  ;
In       : 'in' ;
```